# CSS media queries and elements width

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Does the width specified in the media queries represent the size of devide screen or it is the inner width of the browser in the mobile device.

If I specify an element width same as `min-width` defined in media query, will a horizontal scrollbar appear at some point?

For example:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 460px) and (max-width: 800px){

    .wrapper{
        width: 460px;
    }
}
```

If that's not correct, what should be maximum width of `.wrapper` in order to avoid the scroll bar?

Comment: Share your example at [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: http://tripleodeon.com/2011/12/first-understand-your-screen/ and http://tripleodeon.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/table.html this will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According w3c width in media queries is

> The ‘width’ media feature describes the width of the targeted display
>   area of the output device.

For screen it will be width of browser window.

You can use `device-width` feature to make your markup responsive to device screen.

W3c specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#width